# Cannot find solution to decryption problem using sharedpreferences

Tags: java, encryption, sharedpreferences

Im making an app in android studio using Java which is going to be like a password vault. So the user registers, logs in and can then add login details to various websites, the details get encrypted and the user has to re enter their main account password to decrypt the details. The problem im having is that during the decrypting process when im comparing the input password with the encrypted password, the encrypted password variable never gets updated.

This class is the registration activity, the page where the user first registers themselves.

```
// Create a new User instance (This will integrate with the Room database)
            User newUser = new User(firstName, lastName, email, password);

            // Use ExecutorService to insert the user on a background thread
            executorService.submit(() -> {
                try {
                    AppDatabase.getInstance(RegisterActivity.this).userDao().insertUser(newUser);

                    // Log success
                    Log.d("Registration", "User registered successfully: " + newUser.getEmail());

                    // Store the password in SharedPreferences
                    storeUserPassword(RegisterActivity.this, password);
                    //storeUserPassword(RegisterActivity.this, password);

                    // Show a toast message on the main thread
                    mainHandler.post(() -> {
                        String message = "Registration successful for " + firstName + " " + lastName;
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    });

                    // Navigate back to the login activity on the main thread
                    mainHandler.post(() -> onBackPressed());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Log error
                    Log.e("Registration", "Error inserting user: " + e.getMessage());

                    // Show a toast message on the main thread
                    mainHandler.post(() -> Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Error during registration", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());
                }
            });
        });
```

```
private void storeUserPassword(Context context, String password) {
        try {
            // Generate a salt and hash the password
            String hashedPassword = PasswordUtils.hashPassword(password);

            // Store the hashed password in SharedPreferences
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
            sharedPreferences.edit()
                    .putString("userPassword", hashedPassword)
                    .apply();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Handle hashing and storage error
        }
    }
```

This is the password entry adapter class

```
confirmButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String enteredPassword = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
            // Check if the entered password is correct
            if (verifyPassword(context, enteredPassword)) {
                passwordDialog.dismiss();
                // Decrypt and show the login details dialog
                showDecryptedPasswordDetailsDialog(entry);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Incorrect password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

```
private boolean verifyPassword(Context context, String enteredPassword) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String storedHashedPassword = sharedPreferences.getString("userPassword", "");

        String enteredHashedPassword = PasswordUtils.hashPassword(enteredPassword);

        Log.d("PasswordDebug", "Stored Hash: " + storedHashedPassword);
        Log.d("PasswordDebug", "Entered Hash: " + enteredHashedPassword);

        return enteredHashedPassword.equals(storedHashedPassword);
    }
```

```
private String decryptData(String encryptedData, String userPassword) {
        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
            keyStore.load(null);
            KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry secretKeyEntry = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry("password_key", null);
            SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyEntry.getSecretKey();

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(CryptoUtils.generateIV()));

            byte[] decodedData = Base64.decode(encryptedData, Base64.DEFAULT);
            byte[] decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(decodedData);

            return CryptoUtils.decrypt(new String(decryptedData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8), secretKey);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }
```

This is the code that is supposed to take the encrypted password and decrypt it and set its string value to the sharedpreferences object which im retrieving the string value from to then make the comparison

```
public static String decrypt(String encryptedText, SecretKey secretKey) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(generateIV()));

            byte[] decodedData = Base64.decode(encryptedText, Base64.DEFAULT);
            byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(decodedData);

            return new String(decryptedBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

```
 public static byte[] generateIV() {
        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] iv = new byte[16]; // 16 bytes for AES IV
        secureRandom.nextBytes(iv);
        return iv;
    }
```

This is the CryptoUtils class where the encryption and decryption happens

```
public class CryptoUtils {

    private static final String KEY_ALIAS = "my_secret_key_alias";
    private static final int GCM_IV_LENGTH = 12; // 96 bits

    public static SecretKey generateSecretKey() throws Exception {
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
        KeyGenParameterSpec keyGenParameterSpec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_ALIAS,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                .build();
        keyGenerator.init(keyGenParameterSpec);
        return keyGenerator.generateKey();
    }

    public static byte[] generateIV() {
        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] iv = new byte[16]; // 16 bytes for AES IV
        secureRandom.nextBytes(iv);
        return iv;
    }


    public static String encrypt(String input, SecretKey secretKey, byte[] iv) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());
        return Base64.encodeToString(encryptedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }


    public static String decrypt(String encryptedText, SecretKey secretKey) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(generateIV()));

            byte[] decodedData = Base64.decode(encryptedText, Base64.DEFAULT);
            byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(decodedData);

            return new String(decryptedBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

When im debugging it is just an empty string value. So I even hardcoded the encrypted password so they would definitely match but then since they are string objects they can be the "same" objects but their hashcodes differ, and that is where my problem got bigger. Im completely out of ideas on how to keep debugging. If you do not understand or have a hard time trying to follow the logic, please tell me so I can show you more of the code.

Comment: In your "decrypt" and "decryptData" methods you are using "generateIV()". Although you don't show the code I'm assuming you are generating a **new** initializing vector, but you need to store the IV used on encryption and use the stored IV for decryption later. B.t.w.: why don't you use **Encrypted Shared Preferences** ?

Comment: Just noticed I missed to add that part, it is now added. I have not looked into encrypted shared preferences, how would they help me in my case? Does it remove the need to encrypt and remove passwords every time?

Comment: **Encrypted Shared Preferences** storing credentials the same like Shared Preferences but secured by an AES-GCM based encryption scheme, so you don't need to have your own crypto scheme that can easily get insecure (e.g. if you are using an IV that was not generated securely and random). Second: your "PasswordUtils.hashPassword" method may be insecure [not shown here] e.g. because a key derivation like PBKDF2 is using a much to short number of iterations like 1..9999. So there are a lot of reasons to use the Encrypted Shared Preferences.

Comment: Just one hickup on Encrypted Shared Preferences: as the key that is used to generate the "MasterKey" is stored within your Android's keystore it is NOT part of any backup mechanism by Google, so if you change your device the app on the new device needs to setup all the keys again.

Comment: Alright so what do you think is the best way to go at the moment? I know that my encryption works, the password gets encrypted its just during the comparison section where the password never gets passed through the sharedpreferences to the variable im storing the decrypted password.

Comment: As you didn't show the crypto code parts it is impossible to give an advice, just the general advice "don't run your own crypto".

Comment: Added the entire cryptoutils class that im using, hopefully it clears some of the question marks!

Comment: Your issue persists because - as mentioned in my first comment - you are **generating a new IV when DECRYPTING**. As your algorithm is "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding" the decrypt method will throw an exception and returns "null" - that is the result you are seeing - nothing. Store the IV generated when encrypt (e.g. in Shared Preferences) and use it for decryption.

Comment: Ive tried several changes now, even asked chatGPT as a final precaution if I missed anything but it did not work. For instance in my encrypt method Im generating a secret key that is mapped to the iv generated by the method generateIV(). Then in decrypt I just use the secret key, is that what causes the problem? Otherwise I can't see what the problem is in the code.

Comment: You remember an early comment of mine - "don't roll out your own crypto" ? See my previous comment - save the generated IV on encryption and use THIS IV for decryption. What part of this statement seems to be unclear ?